# automate scheduling queries in Bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have several queries that are scheduled. But the annoying thing is that every time I change something in my code I have to delete the "old scheduled query" and create a "new scheduled query."

All my queries are views.

Is there any way to automate these scheduled queries? One way I know is to create SP's. And call these queries, but the issue with that is that SP's use tables and not views. And tables cost a lot more money then views (I think).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to edit a scheduled query, in the UI when you go to schedule queries click on the name of the query you want to change. Then click the edit button in the menu.

This will load the query back into the editor, you can then change the query as needed. Once finished editing click on the schedule query drop-down and select update schedule query. You can also change the schedule at this point.